# how to create image slider with left and right arrow buttons in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need create image slider to move left and right with arrow buttons. please see my existing images here

```
<div class="col-md-3  animated fadeInUp" >
          <div class="tourbox">
            <div style="background-image:url(); width:100%; height:100%;" class="zoom" >
            </div>
            </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center tourboxInner1"><img src="img/icons/info.png" width="30px"></div>
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center tourboxInner">CLASSICAL TOUR</div>

            </div>


            <div class="col-md-3 animated fadeInUp">
            <div class="tourbox">
            <div style="background-image:url(); width:100%; height:100%;" class="zoom" >
            </div>
            </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center tourboxInner1"><img src="img/icons/info.png" width="30px"></div>
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center tourboxInner">TEA COUNTRY TOUR</div>
                </div>
```

[my image slider example link here](https://codepen.io/lilancha/pen/bYraYy)

I need show four images in the page at one time and need move left and right one by one with new images. I am using bootstrap here. how can I do this please help me?

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: yes please see now via My codepen link

Comment: please see this link https://codepen.io/lilancha/pen/bYraYy

Comment: Where's your JavaScript?

Comment: currently I have not use javascripts here...

Comment: using bootstrap

Comment: Have a look at this: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/

Comment: I need scroll one image from My 4 images in one time and need come one new images. please give me that type of example

Answer (score 0):

hey hello Brother may be my answer helped you totally using bootstrap no custom css and js

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
<div class="carousel-item active">
  <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/desktop-year-of-the-tiger-images-wallpaper.jpg" alt="First slide">
</div>
<div class="carousel-item">
  <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/Embed/new/embed2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
</div>
<div class="carousel-item">
  <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_fjords.jpg" alt="Third slide">
</div>
</div>
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
<span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
<span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
</div>
```

here is working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a2u1vhLp/1/)

Comment: dear I need scroll one image from My 4 images at one time. I need that type of example.

Comment: you dont want auto scroll..??? right..??? you want this example..[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a2u1vhLp/2/)